# Is it possible to say where the lampstand was in the tabernacle?

Tags: exodus, tabernacle

The golden altar of incense was in front of the vail, behind which vail was the ark of the testimony, Exodus 30:6 and Exodus 40:5.

As to the lampstand (I prefer not to say 'candlestick' as it was an oil apparatus) the only reference I can find is Exodus 40:4 :

> ... and thou shalt bring in the candlestick, and light the lamps thereof [KJV]

There is, perhaps, an implication (in this particular verse) that the lampstand was placed, centrally, on the golden altar.

Is there any other scripture that would indicate more of the exact position of the lampstand ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The position of the lampstand and the table of shewbread are described in Ex 40:24 -

> He also placed the lampstand in the Tent of Meeting opposite the table
> on the south side of the tabernacle

Thus, in the Holy Place of the Tabernacle, we have:

- the lampstand on the south
- the table of shewbread on the north side
- the entrance on the east side
- the altar of incense on the west side

I found this somewhere on the web that appears to agree with the description in Exodus.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, Appreciated. Up-voted and accepted as answer.